# R studio has very slow response for clicks and typing after API keras model tranied, why?

Tags: r, keras, rstudio

I am currently working in R Studio and I am working with packages rBayesianOptimization , keras and tensorflow and I am using data set aprox. with 200k rows and 120 columns (which I dont think is too big). I am building an API model with keras and running it with bayesian optimization. However everytime I run the BO, R studio slows down crazily and has very long response for clicks, scrolling through code and typping. I have to turn it off and then on again if I want to analyze the results, so each time I run it I have to store everything so that I can analyze it in new session. Any ideas what could be wrong, or how to solve this? (I have windows with 32gb ram. )

EDIT: the rest things of computer are OK,only RStudio is problematic. This behaviour is also if I train the model only on 5000 samples.

Comment: When I play youtube videos on my desktop while waiting for keras model to train (tensorflow as a backend)- the videos slow down and become grainy.... might be a similar problem...

Comment: interesting. I am not playing videos, but all the rest on omputer seems to work ok, only RStudio is crazy slow.

Comment: Check your memory and swap usage, usually when I have some calculation that generates or consumes big amounts of data (which uses lots of memory), things start slowing down when swap gets almost full

Comment: but this happens after the algorithm finish. I have a result, I want to analyze it, but R studio is too slow to do something. I thought that memory is used while it is computing, but also afterwards ?

Comment: I know this RStudio bug, I use `CTRL + L` or `cat("\014")` from time to time to clear the console. Genuine R GUI is still _much_ faster, though.

Comment: This has not solved the problem, the response for each click or up/down move is still too slow, I have to turn it off and on again. The interesting part is that when I save my enviro and then load it again to new session, it is not slow. It is slow only after computation.